# PYGAME: how to activate event by pressing a key

Tags: python, events, types, pygame, undefined

So I'm having trouble with activating sound, when pressed a key.

what i have so far is

```
if event.type == pygame.key(K_a):
    self.sound.play()
```

I get the error code called global name 'K_a' is not defined.

If anyone can help me correct this code? Thanks!

Comment: Thats probably not solving your problem, but did you try to do `if event.type == K_a:`?

Comment: And did you import everything for pygame? `from pygame import *`

Comment: It can even be that you didn't use the constant pygame.K_a

Answer (score 3):

You should use `pygame.K_a`. This way:
`if event.type == pygame.key(pygame.K_a):`.
 If it doesn't works for you, then you've probably didn't import pygame as needed. Import pygame this way: `from pygame import *`. You may have an error with pygame.key, Because you shouldn't use it this way. The best practice is to use the following line:
`if event.type == pygame.K_a:`